# how to edit data where number have slash

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

my table have

```
no order | Description
1/R/2017 | Vegetable
2/R/2017 | Meal
```

how to edit my Description if in no order have slash on it 1/R/2017
if just value 1 no issue but if data have slash i cant edit

cause in my header show like this
http://localhost/master/master_order/ajax_edit//985/IV/2017
maybe cause that url i cant edit my order with 985/IV/2017 my ajax think thats part of url so they just dislpay behind slash "2017"

this my view

```
function edit_master_order(Nomor)
{
    save_method = 'update';
    $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // clear error class
    $('.help-block').empty(); // clear error string

    //Ajax Load data from ajax
    $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo site_url('master_order/ajax_edit/')?>/" + Nomor,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {

            $('[name="Noorder"]').val(data.Noorder);
            $('[name="Description"]').val(data.Description);            
            $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when complete loaded
            $('.modal-title').text('FORM EDIT MEDIA ORDER'); // Set title to Bootstrap modal title

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error get data from ajax');
        }
    });
}
```

this my controller

```
public function ajax_edit($Noorder)
    {
        $data = $this->master_order->get_by_id($Noorder);
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

and my respone display null if i have to use URI_encode how that code pls help

Answer (score 1):

Hello if you want to edit the data with '/' so you need to divide the string you can do this by using explode() of php

```
$result = explode('/','1/R/2017');
```

so it will give the output as per below

```
$result[0]//1
$result[1]//R
$result[2]//2017
```

Now you can do operation on this array and then after you can merge it, like this

```
$r = $result[0].'/'.$result[1].'/'.$result[2];
```

so this will output the value as per your db preview, i hope this will help you

Comment: im trying using ur code for the half way without array result its works to show in front letter my $Noorder where "1/R/2017" the edit show result "1" but after add
$result[0]//1
$result[1]//R
$result[2]//2017 
i got message Undefined offset: 1 why?

Comment: can you show me how you have implement the code that i have provided, so i can be able to understand more-thank you

Comment: `public function ajax_edit($Nomor)
 {
  $data = $this->master_order->get_by_id($Nomor);
 // $data->dob = ($data->dob == '0000-00-00') ? '' : $data->dob; // if 0000-00-00 set tu empty for datepicker compatibility
  $result = explode('/',$Nomor);
  $result[0];
  $result[1];
  $result[2];
  $data = $result[0].'/'.$result[1].'/'.$result[2];
  echo json_encode($data);
 }`

Comment: which values and field $Nomor contain? because it contains dates then i need to refer it.

Comment: contains $Nomor = "1/R/2017" if using $result = explode('/',$Nomor); $result[0]; just display "1" i need array to read "R" and "2017" that maybe after combine all array ur logic its correct

Comment: ok you making little mistake `$result[0]` is giving you 1, then `$result[1]` will give you R, and `$result[2]` will give you 2017, try this will print which returns in explode array then you come to know what you are getting from the explode  `print_r($result);`

Answer (score 0):

Just using **explode** and **list** in php :

```
public function ajax_edit($noorder){
    list($nomor, $cat, $year) = explode("/", $noorder);
    // $nomor contain : 1, $cat : R, and $year : 2017
    $data = $this->master_order->get_by_id($nomor);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

And also, i see double slash "//" in your request URL, try using GET parameters, so your request URL will look like : http://localhost/master/master_order/ajax_edit?id=985/IV/2017. Get your id parameter using :

```
$noorder = $this->input->get('id');
```

Comment: Hi Galih, need help im using ur code get message Undefined offset: 2

Answer (score -1):

Just change your request type into POST:

```
    var data_input = { no_order : Nomor } //Nomor is from parameter
    $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo site_url('master_order/ajax_edit/')?>",
        type: "POST",
        data: data_input,
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {
           //console.log( data ); //check if existing variable has desired value
           alert( data ); //if it shows 'object' if result exist
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error get data from ajax');
        }
    });
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function ajax_edit()
{
    $no_order = $this->input->post( 'no_order' );
    $data = $this->master_order->get_by_id($no_order);
    if ( count( $data ) != 0 ) {
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
    else {
        echo "No result found";
    }
}
```

Comment: im using ur code my ajax not show anything after delete var data_input = { no_order : Nomor } my ajax list normal again but still cannot edit no_order and still output "Null"

Comment: After doing ajax, press F12 on keyboard then select `console` tab. Your output wiil be shown there.

Comment: hi Ukasyah, yup F12 see in response "Null"

Comment: If `$data = $this->master_order->get_by_id($no_order);`, then what is the value of `$no_order`? Is it integer `ex:1`, or string `ex:1/R/2017`?

Comment: its contain string "1/R/2017"